# Meaning of Auth in PayPal(Standard) Subscribe Button Return URL?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I have a subscribe button (using PayPal Payments Standard Integration) in my WordPress website.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="FRG9AB9A93MUN">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Premium Subscription">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="321">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="299.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I am testing the functionality using PayPal Sandbox. I use WordPress PayPal Framework Plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework)

### My Question

Upon successful payment(subscription), buyer returns to the return url with 'auth' and 'form_charset'
(http://example.com/success/?auth=AtKlH609fYvJhW2wmFr9iMmXboz9JEB64TJjNpLVH8d0OlBbnOpn-TeeCvZT6VWOcoo8XG4GD0AeftCUMdNWCAQ&form_charset=UTF-8)

> Can someone explain me the meaning of 'auth' and 'form_charset'? Can I
>   use it to obtain further information about the transaction via NVP
>   API? Then what should be the NVP API method I should use?

I can properly receive IPN messages on these transactions.

### What I have done so far

I am conversant on PayPal Express Checkout Integration, capturing IPN msgs and processing them, etc.

I have read the NVP API methods, requests and responses in the PayPal Guide.
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf

I went through some of the other PayPal Guides as well.

The following question mentions about 'encrypted variable named auth'. But it was not helpful for me.
([Paypal sandbox return url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038080/paypal-sandbox-return-url))

This question also deals with return on success.
([paypal redirect on successful checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471639/paypal-redirect-on-successful-checkout))

Comment: Did you find a way to get transaction details from auth param?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the "rm" parameter to "2". This causes a POST to the success page, with all transaction variables. [Read more here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: Thanks! pointing out 'rm' parameter helped me to understand the process better. Thanks.

Comment: Genius! I've been looking for a way to put extra data on the success page, without needing to use PDT. This is perfect! Thank you soooo much! Now I can validate that a call to my success page is from PayPal (well close enough), and not some random who's stumbled upon the page. I owe you a pint.